# Processing data from two channels and write result to third channel

Tags: multithreading, go, concurrency, channel

I have a solution for the task that compiles and runs but didn’t pass the tests. I just started to learn Go language and at this stage I don’t know how to solve the problem properly. I will be grateful for your help or advice. I’ve included my current code in the post.

The task description.

Write a function: func Merge2Channels(f func(int) int, in1 <-chan int, in2 <- chan int, out chan<- int, n int) in package main.

Description of her work:

- do the following n times
- read one number from each of the two channels in1 and in2, call them x1 and x2.
- calculate f (x1) + f (x2) write the resulting value in out
- The Merge2Channels function must be non-blocking, immediately returning control.
- Function f can work for a long time, waiting for something or performing calculations.

Input format

- The number of iterations is passed via argument n.
- Integers are supplied via the channel arguments in1 and in2.
- The function for processing numbers before addition is passed through the argument f.

Output format

- The channel for outputting the results is passed through the out argument.

My current code is:

```golang
func calc(f func(int) int, x1 int, x2 int, out chan int) {
    out <- f(x1) + f(x2)
}

func Merge2Channels(f func(int) int, in1 chan int, in2 chan int, out chan int, n int) {
  for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
      x1, x2 := <-in1, <-in2
      go calc(f, x1, x2, out)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is at least the third time this exact problem has come up. I think you're supposed to work it out on your own after taking the [tour of go](https://tour.golang.org/), or at least be more specific about your problem. But if you want to cheat, here's [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61973142/how-to-read-function-and-variables-from-user-input-and-pass-them-to-channel).